# If statement using apium and selenium in python desktop testing

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-desktop

I have a problem with if statement in python durring desktop testing using appium and selenium. My method:

```
def test(self, handler):
   if handler.find_element_by_name("Exist"):
       handler.find_element_by_name("No").click()
   else:
       print("OK")
```

First condition works, the test passes and clicks the "No" button.

If I change the condition to one that's false to call the else, I get test failed and `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

I don't know why this is not working. Also, when I use simple wait, eg.

```
WebDriverWait(handler, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Exist")))
```

everything works fine!

Could you help me?

Comment: I am assuming the page is loading and takes time for the element to be useable/interactable.

Comment: When I add ```time.sleep(1)``` before and after each step, it doesn't help, and it's still failed.

Comment: Use time.sleep(10) it might take a while to load.

Comment: Basically webdriver wait polls for the element to be visiblile every 500 ms and then gets the element.

Comment: ```time.sleep()``` will not help, because the condition in which the test clicks the "No" button works, so the window with that button is loaded. Else condition does not require any waiting.

Comment: Anyway, I tried it and it didn't help :(